# First Aid Cheat Sheet

Tags: first-aid

I am assembling a first aid kit for my next hiking trip, and I would like to print and include a basic cheat sheet with essential information on how to treat common ailments. Also, I would like to have a separate short guide for CPR, with clear visuals, so it is the first thing people see if they open the kit. I have searched online but have not found anything satisfactory. Does anybody know of such material?

Comment: Many organizations have this sort of info on their webpage or app. Try Red Cross or St John as well known first-aid organizations. The initialisms such as DRSABCD, RICE, will help get you started.

Comment: https://store.nols.edu/products/wilderness-medicine-pocket-guide is one such guide that I have in my kit. No affiliation other than being certified WFR through NOLS.

Comment: I use the [WMA guide](https://www.wildmed.com/product/the-field-guide-of-wilderness-rescue-medicine/) in my kit. Same as Jon, no affiliation beyond WFR cert/recert through them. I think it's pretty common for people to use the guide issued by the WFR certifying org they take a class through. This way the book language is aligned with what you've learned in class.

Comment: I'd argue the answer to your question depends on your level of medical training. If you have 0 training then arguably no cheat sheet is a perfect cheat sheet. You should know how to use any first aid materials you have, as well as information about any medications you carry (indications/interactions/contraindications/etc). What you carry can help guide your cheat sheet

Comment: If you read German: https://alpenverein.shop/publikationen/sicheramberg/cardfolder-erste-hilfe-1455-12416.

Answer (score 1):

As with learning or improving any skill, the best advice is to *take a course* or *read some books*.

Depending where you live, there should be many *urban* first aid courses and a lesser number of *wilderness* first aid courses to take. There are also a large number of books on first aid for different situations. Some course providers also provide books.

In either case, there is likely to be some kind of "cheat sheet" -- a quick reference guide for critical and common medical problems.
Note, however, that such "sheets" are often quite substantial; more like booklets.

That being said, here are some:

- [NOLS -- Wilderness Medicine Pocket Guide](https://store.nols.edu/products/wilderness-medicine-pocket-guide)
- [Slipstream -- A quick reference guide to WFA](https://wildernessfirstaid.ca/product/slipstream-map-a-quick-reference-guide-to-wfa/)
- [WildMed -- The Field Guide of Wilderness & Rescue Medicine](https://www.wildmed.com/product/the-field-guide-of-wilderness-rescue-medicine/)

Comment: Folks, if you know of other good examples, maybe we can expand the list...

Comment: I find courses (and books) limited, unless you constantly practice and review them

Comment: @njzk2 - True, but it's hard to practice without any patients!